# Import Private Unicode Symbol

Tags: symbols, unicode

I have created an unicode character in the Windows private character editor. How can this character be imported into LaTeX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If LuaTeX or XeTeX can be used, then these symbols can be addressed.
The following example uses font FontAwesome that has all its symbols in the private area:

```
% lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\FA{FontAwesome}

\begin{document}
{\FA ^^^^f188} % U+F188
{\FA\symbol{"F118}} % U+F118
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- There is no point in using a Unicode character directly, because the editor program would not know, which font it would have to use to display the symbol properly.
- In practice, these magic numbers can be hidden in macros. Package `fontawesome` does this:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{fontawesome}
  \begin{document}
    \faBug \faSmileO
  \end{document}
  ```
- Support for non-Unicode TeX compilers (pdfTeX) is much more cumbersome. Type 1 fonts need to be generated. Maximum number of slots are 256 per font.
  TFM font metrics and map files need to be generated.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I do not understand the concept completely.

By now, I have created a own font with icomoon, however, I still do not know how I can insert this to my latex document.